# gtk+ c simulating tab key from code

Tags: c, gtk3

I'm trying to build a Gtk C GUI application and I can't use the mouse or keyboard for it. My input device is an external keypad connected to the application with serial port.

My problem is that I want to switch between some GtkButtons in my form when a key on my keypad is pressed (like when using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key in a GUI applications).

Here's what I tried so far:

```
      GTK_WIDGET_GET_CLASS(widget)->move_focus(widget,GTK_DIR_TAB_FORWARD);
```

But the problem is that the focus is not visible until I actually press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key on my keyboard. When I run the application, it seems as if nothing is happening, but when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> once, I see that focus is changing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I understand the issue, you have an external keypad that you are using for input in your GTK app and need a `tab` key. This is probably a case where you will need to write a custom input handler that will translate whatever key you are pressing on the keypad into a `tab` or other key capable of moving the focus around your form. You can search *gtk custom input key handler* and turn up a number of examples for both gtk2 and gtk3.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I already handled all the keys I need somehow. the only thing not working is just this tab key, and I guess there are better and quicker ways to do what I want.

Answer (score 2):

make sure that GtkWindow is TOP LEVEL type , because for top level window you can access widgets within that window using keyboard TAB key without doing any addition in code for using TAB.
Post your code for more accurate solution.